# In my HTML page justify-content-between not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for the question, but I am new in bootstrap,
in my  user.js file I could not make it work to deploy justify-content-between
Instead my two elements are next to each other like I used justify-content-start

here are my codes:

```html
<div className="col-md-8 mb-4">
                    
                                <div className = "card" style={isVisible? { backgroundColor : "#88b69f",color : "white"} :null}>
                                    <div className="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
                                       <h4 className="d-inline" onClick={this.onClickEvent}>{name + "    "} </h4>
                                        <i onClick = {this.ondeleteuser.bind(this, dispatch)} className="far fa-trash-alt"  style={{cursor : "pointer"}}></i>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    {                        
                                        this.state.isVisible ?
                                        <div className="card-body">
                                        <p className="card-text">Maaş : {salary}</p>
                                        <p className="card-text">Departman : {department}</p>
                                        
                                        </div>:null
                                    }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: I forget that I have another problem : At the tutorial , the header's color is grey but mine is white as the main background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I understand that in my public/index.html file in  section had not correct links to bootstrap links. 
I found an original html file from our tutors github page and I replace all  section of his project to mine and that is it. It is solved. 
This two lines should exist in index.html file :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want space between h4 and i element? If yes, then `<i>` will not be a child of `<h4>`. Try the below code snippet. It should solve your problem.

```
<div className="col-md-8 mb-4"><div className="card" style={isVisible? { backgroundColor : "#88b69f" ,color : "white" } :null}>
<div className="card-header d-flex justify-content-between">
  <h4>{name + " "}</h4>
    <i onClick={this.ondeleteuser.bind(this, dispatch)} className="far fa-trash-alt" style={{cursor : "pointer"}}></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry it did not work , even worse because now chid i dropped 1 row down and onClick even not works now

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have there only one element in that `div`, if there'd be another sibling to `h4` it should have worked.

Comment: 1- The problem is when I divide the div into 2 siblings second one automatically drops down. And in the tutorial I watch there is both laying in the same line ; one in he start one in the end.
2- At the tutorial , the header's color is grey but mine is white as the main background color

Answer (score 0):

`justify-content: space-between` on a parent element works to space out its children. In your case, the `div` which has `justify-content: space-between` has only one child, so there is nothing to space out. The `h4` then has its own text child and a child `i`.

Your current structure is:

```
div.justify-content-between
    h4
        i
```

There are a number of ways to convert to having two children on the `div`. The option you proceed with will depend on your use-case and preference. One example is to put the `i` in a separate `h4`:

```
div.justify-content-between
    h4
    h4
        i
```

Comment: I did this (put i in a h4 element) but the first h4 and i element are not in the same row or same header or in the same line, it drops 1 row down

Comment: If you have already separated the h4 and i out to be siblings and you have verified the parent has both the `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` properties successfully set on it, the only thing I can think of is that the width of the content of each child combines to be greater than the width of the parent, which would cause the second child to fall to the next line.

Comment: So AFAIU I need to make some changes on my .css file ... 
Thanks  JustinTRoss